# Redirect except this folder css or js or image

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect except this folder css or js or image and is not working.

I have tried below code-

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^(css|js|image)
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ find.php?term=$1&type=test&path=1 [L,QSA]
```

and

```
RewriteRule ^([^(css|js|images|/)]+)/?$ find.php?term=$1&type=test&path=1 [L,QSA]
```

But it is not working.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You need match against `℅{REQUEST _URI}` instead of `℅{REMOTE _HOST}` .

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !\.(css|js|image)
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ find.php?term=$1&type=test&path=1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: It works! it is not exclude png jpg gif images, I tried like this`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !\.(css|js|png|jpg|gif)`